# Best practice to get newest row in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Consider a table like this:

[image]

The `id` column is set to auto-increment, `update_time` column is supposed to be the date that the row was inserted in the table.

I want to simply get the latest entry for a user with user_id = x, I found out there are some ways:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_id = x ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_id = x MAX(update_time)
```

And another query would be selecting the row with highest id number

I am not quite sure about the syntax of the later one (please correct me).

This may seem to be a trivial task, but there was a case that someone else has altered the auto_increment value on the table, and sometimes the time of the server has changed (well this has not been happened in my case but what if it does!!?)

What would be the safest query to get the latest entry row for a user_id ( I mean a query to return weigh, height and activity_level for a user with user_id = x)

Do I need to add more columns to the table? if so, what?

Comment: Is your user_id unique field? What you said "I want to simply get the latest entry for a user with user_id = x" made me think there cane be duplicate user_id

Comment: If it is unique, it doesn't matter if the auto increment key is changed or update_time is changed. You are always going to get the same value for that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the join approach for this.  Assumes that userID + update_time is unique...it'll pull back multiple rows if it isn't.

```
select user_id, max(update_time) maxtime from table group by user_id
```

Simple statement to get the max update time by user ID.  Use it as a subquery with inner join (inner join will function as a filter)

```
select t.*
from table t
inner join
 (select user_id, max(update_time) maxtime 
     from table group by user_id
      --where user_id = x
       )a
on a.user_id = t.user_id and a.maxtime = t.update_time
```

I commented out the where user_id = x line...the advantage to this method is you can get all users and their most recent at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_id = x AND update_time = (SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM mytable WHERE user_id = x)
```

Comment: need a from statement in your subquery

Answer (score 1):

This really does not have to be so complicated:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE user_id = x
ORDER BY update_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This version will be the quickest, simplest, and easiest to read. It is a win in every regard.